# How do I fill in a custom polar-coordinate shape in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a Valentine's Day project and hit a snag making a polar chart in ggplot2.

I want to fill in a heart shape. I have two equations that give reasonable results. The first effectively scribbles lines around the desired shape.

```
library(tidyverse)


t <- seq(-pi,pi,0.001)
x <- 16*0.25*(3*sin(t) - sin(3*t))
y <- 13*cos(t) - 5*cos(2*t) - cos(4*t)

Heart1 <- tibble(x,y)

Heart1Plot <- Heart1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_line(color = "pink") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank()) +
  coord_polar(start = pi)
Heart1Plot
```

[image: Heart scribble outline]

The second one creates a crisp outline.

```
r <- 2 - 2*sin(t) + sin(t)*(sqrt(abs(cos(t))))/(sin(t)+1.4)

Heart2 <- tibble(t,r)

Heart2Plot <- Heart2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(t,r)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_line() +
  coord_polar(start = pi/2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "pink") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank())
Heart2Plot
```

[image: Crisp outline]
You can see I'm currently trying to use ggplot2::scale_fill_manual() to color inside the shape, but it isn't working. I also tried ggplot2::scale_fill_discrete() with similarly non-existent results. What do I need to do to put a color inside the shape? The second heart is more important, but I think the first heart may need a different method because of how it's drawn. Thank you!

Comment: For the second plot, just replace `geom_line()` with `geom_polygon()`.

Comment: @teunbrand, thank you! geom_polygon() fulfilled my needs well enough. I think I'll try a color patch behind the polygon for the first heart. I noticed you removed something I start my scripts with (clearing the console). Was it just unnecessary for the post, or do you think that is a bad practice in general?

Comment: It clears the session's environment, not necessarily the console. `rm(list = ls())` is simultaneously too extreme and not extreme enough. It's too extreme in the sense that people who blindly copy-paste your code might lose some important work. It's also not extreme enough, in that it isn't the same as starting a new R session. Namespaces attached and global options set are unchanged. See also last paragraph here: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/